# Can an attacker modify data so that the hashing technique cannot detect the change?

Tags: hash

I'm just curious as to if this is possible or not?

Comment: https://shattered.io/

Comment: If they can modify the reference hash as well, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

Not for any well-known hashes, not even the extremely broken MD5. You're describing a second preimage attack, but virtually every hash known to be "broken" is only vulnerable to collision attacks.

Caveat: if the attacker had any control over the "good" data, then they could use a collision attack to accomplish this.

Comment: I disagree with the MD5 part. Have a look at: https://natmchugh.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-i-created-two-images-with-same-md5.html for example.

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox That's a collision, because the attacker had to modify the content of both images to achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

### Cryptographic hash vs ordinary hash functions

There are all kinds of hash functions, used (for example) in error correcting codes and hash table data structures, and for many of them it *is* possible to do so

However, for *cryptographic* hash functions that is unacceptable. If it turns out that for a particular function it's actually possible to do so, then we'd consider it "broken" and not suitable for use as a cryptographic hash. So for all currently accepted cryptographic hash functions (which IMHO don't include MD5 anymore) we believe that an attacker can't modify data in an undetectable way.

It is theoretically possible that a highly advanced attacker has found out some mathematical vulnerability that allows them to do so for a particular hash. Perhaps NSA knows a particular way how SHA3 is broken, and in that case they might be able to do so; but as to the best of our knowledge that isn't currently possible.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I don't think anyone would disagree that MD5 shouldn't be considered a secure cryptographic hash anymore (or SHA1 for that matter), but MD5 _is_ still secure against preimages, as Joseph Sible points out.